# Spring integration LastModifiedFileListFilter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I`m trying to read some files from a directory and have a delay between the detection of the file and the process of the file. 
I have this in a builder pattern :

```
/**
 * The build function that will create a CompositeFileListFilter with the given filters
 * 
 * @return {@link CompositeFileListFilter} that contains all the filters added
 */
public CompositeFileListFilter<File> build() {
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    boolean existsFilters = false;
    // Add the prevent duplicates filter
    if (this.preventDuplicates) {
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        existsFilters = true;
    } else {
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<File>());
        existsFilters = true;
    }
    // Add the ignore hidden filter
    if (this.ignoreHidden) {
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
        existsFilters = true;
    } // Add the pattern file name filter
    if (this.patternFilter != null) {
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(patternFilter));
        existsFilters = true;
    }
    // Add the process file after a period of time filter
    if (this.lastModifiedFileListFilterAge > 0) {
        LastModifiedFileListFilter filter = new LastModifiedFileListFilter();
        filter.setAge(lastModifiedFileListFilterAge);
        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(filter);
        existsFilters = true;
    }

    // Check if compositeFileListFilter contains any filter
    if (!existsFilters) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("At least one filter should be provided!");
    }
    return compositeFileListFilter;
}
```

and i`m creating the filters like this

```
CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new IntegrationFlowFileFilterBuilder()
        .ignoreHidden(true)
        .preventDuplicates(false)
        .patternFilter(returnInformationInputFolderSetup.getPatternFolder())
        .lastModifiedFileListFilterAge(120)
        .build();
```

The problem is that all the other filters are working and only theLastModifiedFileListFilter is not working.. i`m reading a file and is processed in less than a second.
Does anyone know why this filter is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested your use-case with the:

```
@Test
public void testLastModifiedInComposite() throws IOException {
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.foo"));
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileListFilter(120));

    given(this.fileMock.getName())
            .willReturn("test.foo");

    given(this.fileMock.lastModified())
            .willReturn(System.currentTimeMillis());

    List<File> filteredFiles = compositeFileListFilter.filterFiles(new File[] { this.fileMock });

    assertTrue(filteredFiles.isEmpty());

    compositeFileListFilter.close();
}
```

Pay attention that I specify the current time for the `lastmodified` and this file indeed doesn't path `LastModifiedFileListFilter`. Therefore I get an empty result. Just because my file is too young to be accepted by the `LastModifiedFileListFilter`.

I would suggest you to debug the `CompositeFileListFilter.filterFiles()` method to be sure what really is going on.

Also pay attention that there is a `ChainFileListFilter` for a bit different point of view for the filtering functionality: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: Thanks for help. The problem was that i copied the file in the polling folder the files was older than 120 seconds and the LastModifiedFileListFilter check the Last Modified Time of the file. Anyway thanks for the tip with  ChainFileListFilter. now the algorithm is more efficient.